# the trust relationship between this workstation and the primary domain failed windows 8

Tags: windows, login, windows-8

I have a Windows 8 computer which is being used for testing.
For some reason, after restart, I get the following error:

> the trust relationship between this workstation and the primary
>   domain failed windows 8

I've read in google, and saw some solutions, but none of them work for me, since I can't connect locally and I also don't have the administrator password (my sysadmin is sick at home....).

Any way around this?

Answer (score 0):

There could be several reasons to get this error.  The most common I have seen as that it was removed from Active Directory in some way.

The easiest way to fix this is to rejoin the domain.  The easiest way to do this would be to log in the Win 8 computer, but you cant seem to connect.

Try disconnecting the Win 8 machine from the network and logon using credentials that work.  Hopefully they have administrator access.  Once you are in, you should be able to rejoin the domain.

Comment: I fear that there are no local users on the machine but the sysadmin....Any other ways? There used to be a local Administrator account on Windows 7 and its predecessors, does it exist in Windows 8?

Comment: Another reason can be that somehow 2 computers have joined the domain using the same name! I faced this issue once.

Answer (score 0):

**Virtually all solutions require being able to log on to the machine in some way**

While it isn't necessary to rejoin the machine, you do have to be able to get on to the machine in order to establish the trust.  If you unplug the network cable from the machine, you might be able to sign on with locally saved credentials assuming you have signed into the machine before.  The following is far easier than joining the domain again, but it must be run from a command prompt on the machine.

```
netdom.exe resetpwd /s:<server> /ud:<user> /pd:*

<server> = a domain controller in the joined domain

<user> = DOMAIN\User format with rights to change the computer password
```